# why a protectd method of a class can nor be accessed by creating its object in sub class?

Tags: c#-2.0

i have a code like this, but giving error can not access protected member.

```
**Class A
{
protected void m1()
       {
        some code
       }
}
Class B:A
{
B b=new B();
b.m1();// Ok works fine
A a =new a();
a.m1();///   don't work, compile time error
A a2=new B();
a2.m1(); //compile time error, don't work
}**
```

just not getting reason behind this, Why so aberrant nature of the above code, why a method of a class using same class object not accessible out side. While i searched a bit for this but did not undersand, i found something that compiler nature come in picture, but i did not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can prefix your call by `base` keyword for calling base members. `protected` means that a member could be inherited by descendants and could be called but through the specified way.

calling `a.m1()` in your class hasn't any difference with calling it form an out of **B** code.

Comment: how? "calling a.m1() in your class hasn't any difference with calling it form an out of B code.". While i am calling m1() from sub class where it is available....how i it not accessible?

Comment: It's a protection level that be applied by access modifiers like private and protected . it means that accessing a member through an object is not permitted,otherwise that member is public if anyone have access to it, but accessing that member in methods of that class and it's descendants(in the case of protected members not privates) is legal

Comment: so, suppose in the above code, i have a third class say C which don't inherit any, in that case if i create object of class B in the class c and try to access the protected method of class A, will it be accessible? and if not then why?

Comment: Sure you can't. protected members is just like private members. let clear the meaning of private members and probably you get the idea. private members just can be use in the in the body of methods that is in class not outside, it's the information hiding principle in object oriented languages, so for clients to be aware of internals of a an object there must be Public method or properties that mediate the access and control it.

Comment: sn can we call a private method of a class on an object of same class in the same class?

Comment: No you can't, just in the body of method in class

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, the protected method inside the class can only be accessed by the class that inherits the original container.In your case B is the sub class, a is your base. Inside your B class you are creating a new instance of A class ('a'), and this is now a different object (B class does not care about this new object A). This new object 'a' will not expose the protected method, so 'a.m1()' will throw a compile error.

Comment: so method is like static, it does not belong to an object of A class?